# TImer is not working properly in java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

here is my `Timer` scheduler

```
   timer.schedule(new SuperOne(),new Date(),10);
```

In `SuperOne` class in `run`method i am calling `synchronized` method By using above code That task is only working once.

My requirement is that It has to call the `synchronized` method for every minute(60 seconds). 
Here timer scheduler is not working what I expect ... Is it because I am running `synchronized` method ?

Please help me In this

**EDIT:  Its working for first time (calling one time ) and not calling after 10 milliseconds **

This is the code has to run

```
    private boolean proxyEnabled=false;
public synchronized void statusChecker()
{
    StopWatch sWatch = new StopWatch();

    ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.application");
    System.out.println(resource.getString("url"));

    try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;


    if(proxyEnabled) {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxYhost", portNumber));
        sWatch.start();
        urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        System.out.println(urlConnection);
    } else {
        urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        sWatch.start();
    }

     System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

    if(in!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("The resopose TIme is  -- >"+ sWatch.toString());
    }else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }



    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }finally
    {
        sWatch.stop();
    }
}
```

Class which extends `TimerTask`

```
   public class SuperOne extends TimerTask{



boolean flag = false;

@Override

public synchronized void run()  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        System.out.println("*** * ** Thread started ** ** *** ");
            Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println(th.isAlive());
        CheckServer cs  = new CheckServer();
        cs.statusChecker();



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in Run IterFace "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
 }
```

Comment: For starters, your code schedules the task every 10 milliseconds. That might not be what you want.

Comment: _"timer scheduler is not working what I expect"_ - how is it working and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: pls show full code if you can

Comment: What you mean full code /

Comment: Real code what you have written for Timer and Task

Comment: Please post the `run()` method for `SuperOne()`. Also, Ben asked a good question: if you want the task to run once every minute, why are you scheduling it to run once every 10 milliseconds? For debugging purposes, perhaps once a second would make more sense, particularly if the `run()` method takes any significant time to complete.

Comment: I tried with `1000` milliseconds no change having problem again

Answer (score 1):

You've made `run` `synchronized`, which means that only one thread can every access that function at a time (which means realistically only one task can ever be active at a time). I do not believe this is what you intended to do. I imagine what you intended to do was make what `run` calls during its execution `synchronized`, so that only one of the running tasks can call it at a time to ensure consistency.

A lot of people get tripped up on exactly what `synchronized` does, because it doesn't do what a lot of people expect it to (although it does do what its name implies if you think about common use cases for it). See the Java [synchronized tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for more.